# Length of content in varchar using JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have the following query using SQL

```
SELECT count(*) FROM nuts WHERE nuts_code LIKE '%ES%' AND level=3 AND LENGTH(nuts_code)=4
```

But I need to translate this query to JPA Repository and I have the following code in Java.

```
List<Nuts> findAllByLevelAndNutsCodeContaining(Integer lev,String nutsCode);
```

I don't know how to use LENGTH property on JPA Repository . Could anyone help to me ?

Regards

Comment: by jpa you mean spring-data-jpa?

Comment: yes using spring data jpa

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I believe that there is no way to do what you want with SPeL, i.e. encode this in a repositotry method name.